# En mi programa me tira un error de NullReferenceException

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2013

Estoy haciendo un programa de un juego, al momento de probar una etapa me salió un error [image: error]

la coloque un punto de debug y en la variable mapRow no tiene nada (la variable mapRow tiene el mapa del juego completo, es un arreglo de 30 posiciones que esta lleno de w , . , o) cuando en realidad tendria que tener el mapa de todo el juego

Esta es lo que contiene la variable mapRow
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Varias cosas. El codigo debe ir como texto, no como una imagen. Las imagenes son dificiles de ver. Vos mismo ya notaste cual es el problema, mas que eso no vamos apoder ayudarte. Esta pregunta ya esta contestada, y te paso ahora el link

Comment: gracias por tu comentario